# Calling Stored Procedure on Table Update T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am currently working creating a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014. Ideally, I would like to invoke some setting so that each time a certain table in my database updates, the stored procedure is run again (I'm not sure if it matters, but the stored procedure queries the table that it is looking for the update on). I have looked at documentation for both T-SQl and SQl Server, but I am unable to find any information confirming or denying whether or not this is feasible. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Look at triggers. You nearly defined their behavior with what you want to do.

Comment: Triggers are what you need.

Comment: There is an "inserted" table inside the trigger.  Be very careful writing voodoo logic inside a trigger that goes back to the (same) Table.  Hopefully you're just reading some of that data...and trying to update or delete it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server has triggers that can be created on tables which will fire on operations done to the table.  For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AfterUpdate
ON mydatabase.mytable
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS
   EXEC myStoredProc
GO
```

You can read more about triggers in the documentation.  [Creating Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms189799.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)